# spring mvc controller doesn't handle pure ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I have next controller method on server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/templates/test"}, method = 
RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String TestURL(@RequestBody List<String> testString,
                          Model model,
                          Locale locale) {
        return testString.toString();
    }
```

preconditions on UI (java script):

```
var statList = [];
            statList.push('aaa');
            statList.push('bbb');
var strList = JSON.stringify(statList);
```

and 2 ways to call it from client:

1) via jQuery:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'text',
            url: "/templates/test",
            data: strList,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            },
        });
```

- works well. Controller handles request.

2) via pure AJAX:

```
        var myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        myReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        myReq.open("POST", "/templates/test", false);
        myReq.responseType = 'text';
        myReq.send(strList);
```

- doesn't work. Controller doesn't handle request. Method TestURL isn't called at all. Could you help me to fix second request to be able to handle it on controller? Or suggest right spring version for that? My spring version is 4.3.7.

P.S. Next code works well but it is not what i want. i need parsing to List{String}:

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/templates/test"}, method = RequestMethod.POST) // , consumes = "application/json"
@ResponseBody
public String TestURL(@RequestBody String testString,
                      Model model,
                      Locale locale) {
    return testString;
}
```

UI:

```
var myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //myReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                myReq.open("POST", "/templates/test", false);
                myReq.send("aaaa");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple: pure ajax request is wrong. It is not allowed to call setRequestHeader before open request. Besides here if call responseType then async should be true